# What is the best way to handle a large list data set with orientation changing?

Tags: android, list, dataset, android-orientation

I have a very large data set for my base adapter in my Twitter-like app, which consists of custom models (with nested references) which are quite large in themselves.

The issue i'm having is, when re-creating the Activity on orientation change, the list is quite slow to populate (i'm currently passing the data set through `onSaveInstanceState`)

I've looked into changing the way I serialise the models (currently using Kryo which has sped up the saving to disk aspect), caching to disk and reloading in `onCreate`, using `setRetainInstance(true)` in the list fragment, i've also tried handling configuration changes in the parent Activity.

Although the latter is the quickest, it's also the last option I want to take as there's a lot of downsides to handling orientation and would also mean having to re-write chunks of code.

My question is, what is the best practice of handing adapter repopulating on orientation?

I can foresee OOM errors when serialising the list to pass through `onSaveInstanceState`

Edit: Possible duplicate [Best way to persist data between orientation changes in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578025/best-way-to-persist-data-between-orientation-changes-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html. check the docs.

Comment: How do you populate the list to begin with?

Comment: From where did You get Your values? Maybe a database i sa solution

Comment: The list is populated from a HTTP request (or loaded from a cached file if exists)

Comment: Since you're loading only 30 items into the ListView, one option could be to cache only a subset of your data. `The list is populated from a HTTP request (or loaded from a cached file if exists)`. The rest can be retrieved as and when required.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be loading all the data into the listview, only the necessary parts. Look into something like this: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

**Edit:**
You can also use a library like RoboSpice (https://github.com/octo-online/robospice), to handle the caching of the data for you, this will greatly decrease the lag.

Comment: This doesn't help. I'm looking to re-populate my already populated list after an orientation change.

Comment: This does help, because the lag you are having is because there is a lot of data to load, a lot of data you don't need. If you are only loading necessary data you won't have that problem

Comment: I'm actually only loading 30 items into the list. The issue is the actual data, not the views.

Comment: Try the new RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to avoid recreating activity on orientation change:
For this, in app manifest set configChangesAttribute like this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/activity_title"
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```