# Dismiss the MessageDialog in onDestroy() not working?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, messagedialog

To show the Message Dialog while screen is turned on and also retained the dialog on orientation changed.

```
 public void onDestroy()
{  //savedMessageDialog id represents the current MessageDialogId


    //dismiss the message dialog if message id displayed. 
    int savedMessageDialogId = MessageDialog.getSavedMessageDialogId();
    if(savedMessageDialogId == MSG_BACK_DATE_WARNING){
        MessageDialog.dismissMessageDialog();
    }
}
```

and My MessageDialog extends the DialogFragment hence i put this same code in onSavedInstancestate it's working properly no issues Succcess !!!

While I put this code in onDestroy it is creating the multiple instances while many times I changed the orientation and also note that I will dismiss the dialog because of when I am back from turned off to Turn on the Device My dialog shown up. 
and My MessageDialog internally uses the AlertDialog....
in that

```
 private static MessageDialog currentMessageDialog = null;

  public static void dismissMessageDialog()
{
    if (MessageDialog != null && MessageDialog.isAdded()) 
    {
        try 
        {
            currentMessageDialog.dismiss();             
        } 
        catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            currentMessageDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

so please Let me know why i can't dismiss the dialog in onDestroy and why multiple instances are created for MessageDialog ?
Please suggest me some good solution :-)

Comment: Are you getting any error??

Comment: No error ! but multiple instances of the dialog are coming when i changed the Multiple times the orientation.

Comment: On orientation change, activity restarts.. That may be the reason what are you getting multiple insatances..

Comment: Yes, That's true. So Is there any solution that what i'm asking ??

Comment: Be sure to create only one instance using any logic..

Comment: Please try to avoid having static references to dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following to your activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11578706/2591002) for better understanding.

Comment: I can not use android:configChanges =" orientation| screenSize " this because I am using diffrent layouts for tablets and Phones.